# Do I need a covid-test when transiting in Germany?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, paperwork, germany, covid-19

I am a Czech resident, planning to travel from Tel-Aviv Israel to Prague, Czech republic via Frankfurt international airport. I was not able to understand if in this case I need to take a negative Covid test before boarding a plane from Tel-Aviv to Frankfurt?

Comment: If in doubt, get a test. Even if it’s not mandatory and certainly not a guarantee that you don’t have it or will not catch it between the test and the flight, it’s the least you can do to minimise risk for everyone. Also remember that even if today it’s not a requirement it could become one tomorrow.

Comment: @jcaron I am vaccinated, so for me this test is entirely a formality.

Comment: you must have missed the fact that people who have been vaccinated have actually caught the virus and tested positive. Also, even though it should prevent a majority of people of developing the disease, nobody knows yet how efficient it is at preventing people from transmitting the virus. We all hope it will be very efficient at that, but at this time, it’s still an unknown. Also remember that unless you have had the two injections with the right spacing and let a few days pass for the vaccine to take effect, it’s efficacy is a lot lower.

Comment: Just for figures: https://uk.news.yahoo.com/israel-covid-vaccination-data-offers-114641660.html In Israel 317 people who had received both shots still tested positive and 16 ended up in hospital. Much better than those not vaccinated, but definitely not a foolproof guarantee that you can’t be infected and pass it on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answer is wrong!

Per the German [Ministry of Health](https://www.bundesgesundheitsministerium.de/coronavirus-infos-reisende/faq-tests-Einreisende-englisch.html), if you're only transiting Germany, a test is only required if you've been to a "virus variant" country in the past 10 days, which does NOT currently include Israel.

TIMATIC, the database used by airlines, confirms the same:

> Passengers transiting through Germany from Brazil, Ireland (Rep.), Portugal, South Africa or United Kingdom must have a medical certificate with a negative Coronavirus (COVID-19) test result. The test must have been taken at most 48 hours before arrival. Tests accepted are: Antigen, PCR, RT-LAMP and TMA tests. The certificate must be in English, French or German.

(in fact Eswatini and Lesotho were just added, but TIMATIC hasn't yet been updated)

As such, since you're merely a transiting (from Israel), a test is NOT required (nor is online registration).

If you're still not convinced, email the COVID-19 unit of the Frankfurt border police at bpold.frankfurt.kost-covid-19.anfragen@polizei.bund.de. To get the correct information, clearly write that you're arriving from Israel, haven't spent the past 10 days in a "virus variant" country and are simply catching a connecting flight to Prague.

Comment: However, note that the list of countries can be amended easily, and there is no guarantee that Israel won't be on that list at the time the OP wants to travel. The list is purely based on the appearance of mutated strains of SARS-CoV-2 and does not necessarily need a change of the law in order to get updated. It can be updated with a simple order by the Ministery of the Interior.

Comment: Note that the German Ministry of Health notes that "In addition, flights can always be cancelled or delayed. Even a change of terminal can require a border crossing be passed. That means an entry into Germany might be necessary. You should therefore also meet the testing obligation before commencing your journey when solely intending to stop over in Germany (without entering the country). You should also expect that airlines may refuse to take you if you do not meet the testing obligation." Also worth keeping in mind that TIMATIC isn't a good source of information for the past year.

Comment: @DavidMulder Clearing immigration is necessary for non-Schengen -> Schengen transfers anyway, and is allowed on the same terms as non-Schengen -> non-Schengen transfers, in fact even continuing overland is OK. And yes, some countries have been very lazy about keeping TIMATIC updated properly (Denmark notably comes to mind), but the info regarding Germany is, as of now, correct.

Comment: @DavidMulder Plus, I found the official government info https://www.bundesgesundheitsministerium.de/coronavirus-infos-reisende/faq-tests-Einreisende-englisch.html. It talks about "risk areas", "high-risk areas" and "virus variant areas". For transit, a test is only required if having been to a "virus variant" area in the past 10 days. Israel is "just" a "high-risk" country, so no test required for transit

Comment: I don’t think this is correct. As OP travels to another country in the Schengen Area, this does it count as international transit, and the passenger is considered as entering Germany. Coming from a country classified as “risk area” and “high incidence area”, a test is required.

Comment: @jcaron Nope, transit in this case means ANY transit, including non-Schengen -> Schengen and even non-Schengen -> overland. Got it confirmed by the national border police section by email, so email them if you don't believe me (bpolp.referat.22@polizei.bund.de). Furthermore, when arriving from a "risk area" (the lowest degree) and staying (!) in Germany, the (mandatory) test can be done up to 48 hours after entry too.

Comment: @jcaron I think I now see your source of confusion. You refer to "When entering an international transit zone at a German airport..." NOT the right one, but (in OPs case) "What exemptions from the testing obligation apply for high-incidence areas?". Transit is number 2 in that list

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest updates of today, January 31st 2021, concerning Germany available [here](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php) and with reference to what is written on the [website of the Federal Ministry of Health](https://www.bundesgesundheitsministerium.de/coronavirus-infos-reisende/faq-tests-Einreisende-englisch.html)  it seems that the answer to your question is: yes, a test is required.

Comment: Welcome to the site 4dr14n. We do not accept links to sites that have nothing to do with the questions and do not accept signatures. Your chosen screen name will be posted with your answers and questions. You can have a link to your site on your profile page and when relevant you can link to your site as long as you disclose in that post that it is your site. You do need to register to have a profile page and a link there.

Comment: The Ministry of Health link effectively confirms that no test is required if arriving from Israel and only transiting through Germany (can be on a Schengen flight or even overland)